# Zoom in Cropper.js while cropping

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

is is possible in Cropper.js to zoom my image during cropping?

I tried to calculate this zoomIndex in cropend event , but I want to centered this cropped image in the center . but this isn't 100% correct in any cases . is there any built in functionality for that?